# <a> doesn't wrap span, and appears as text

Tags: php, html, anchor

I've used an `<a></a>` tag inside a PHP file. It looks like so:

```
<а href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.imperialhero.android">
    <span class="qr-wrapper"></span>
</a>
```

However, when rendered as HTML on the page, the `span` within is displayed normally (and outside of the anchor element), while the anchor is "seen" as text and displayed like so.

[image]

Why is my link interpreted like text? And why is the closing `</a>` missing?

Comment: So I copied it into a text editor and realised your first `а` isn't an `a`. It's different. Re-write your `a` tag using `a`, not `а`. (Copy and paste the 'a' and put it in google or something as proof it's a different character).

Comment: write manually <a> it will resolved

Comment: Right with @Albzi , it's a character issue, look [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h25k05or/1/)

Comment: SO code formatting also display code in black color that means, something wrong. inside the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your anchor tag seems not to be an "a", but a different symbol that looks like an a. Not sure what it is though. replace it then it should work.

```
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.imperialhero.android">
    <span class="qr-wrapper"></span>
</a>
```

in comparision, yours:

```
<а href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.imperialhero.android">
    <span class="qr-wrapper"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: I really need to configure WebStorm to alert me when I'm not writing in english. It's a cyrillic a. :D

Comment: I think you should close the question as a typo error as this question won't be useful for future visitors as it's very use case specific.

Comment: @GMchris try to configure your editor to display hidden and whitespace characters. Here (https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/editor-appearance.html) you can find how to configure it. Then, will be easy find any kind of typo.